# for loop syntax with containers - Is a copy made?

Tags: c++

I am reading about the new C++11 syntax for iterating over STL containers.
So far I came across the following example:

```
std::vector<int> plus;
....
for(int l : plus)
{
std::cout << l;
}
```

My question is does the above syntax make a copy of the int ?
If so wouldnt this be more efficient ?:

```
for(int& l : plus)
```

Comment: Generally, references are slightly less efficient than copies for `int` and other small types. It won't make much of a difference putting in an unnecessary reference, though.

Comment: If you're using the value of `l` inside the loop by, say, outputting it, it'll get copied anyway. If anything, the first loop is more efficient (and loop 2 can concievably get optimized into it if you never exploit the reference semantics).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semantically, it makes a copy, although for built-in types there may be no efficiency hit, in fact it may even be cheaper to use a copy. But if you have expensive to copy objects, it is a better idea to use `const` references in the loop.

```
std::vector<ExpensiveToCopy> v;
for (const auto& i : v)
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

You should only really use non-const references if you want to mutate the object.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you don't explicitly say you want a reference, you get a copy. With built-in types, its actually more efficient to take a copy - unless you want the semantics of references, of course.

Answer (score 2):

It will call the copy constructor for each element in the vector. If you take it by `const reference`, it doesn't call any constructors at all. You should use `const` if you don't plan on mutating the elements. For example:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Default.\n"; }
    ~Test() { }
    Test(const Test& other) { std::cout << "Copy.\n"; }
    Test(Test&& other) { std::cout << "Move.\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> test;
    test.emplace_back(Test());
    for (const Test& t : test)
    {
    }
}
```